# Class cant get the value of maindow form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am new in c# language, I have a form called `Mainwindow`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ConnectionManager DatabaseConnect = new ConnectionManager();
    LoginController LoginControl = new LoginController();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Done_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoginControl.Login();
    }

    private void Close_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseConnect.ConnectDatabase();
        Username_txtbox.Focus();
    }

    private void Username_txtbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        LoginControl.KeyEnter(e);   
    }

    private void Password_txtbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        LoginControl.KeyEnter(e);
    }

    private void Password_txtbox_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        LoginControl.KeyEnter(e);
    }
}
```

The class LoginController

```
class LoginController
{

    private ConnectionManager DatabaseConnect = new ConnectionManager();

    public void KeyEnter(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {   
            Login();
        }
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        MainWindow MainWindowPage = new MainWindow();
        DatabaseConnect.ConnectDatabase();

        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex EmailOnly = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]{2,28}[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$");
         //Validates the textbox if it does not match the Regular expression of email address.

        if (!EmailOnly.IsMatch(MainWindowPage.Username_txtbox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid email address!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (MainWindowPage.Username_txtbox.Text.Length == 0 || MainWindowPage.Password_txtbox.Password.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter on the login fields.");
            }
            if (MainWindowPage.Username_txtbox.Text != "" && MainWindowPage.Password_txtbox.Password != "")
            {
                DatabaseConnect.SqlStringQuery = "SELECT * FROM login_tbl WHERE user_email = '" + MainWindowPage.Username_txtbox.Text + "' AND password = '" + MainWindowPage.Password_txtbox.Password + "'";
                DatabaseConnect.Getdata();
                if (DatabaseConnect.SQLDR.HasRows == true)
                {
                    DatabaseConnect.SQLDR.Close();
                    AdminForm AdminForm = new AdminForm();
                    AdminForm.Show();
                    MainWindowPage.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    DatabaseConnect.SQLDR.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid user account!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried placing the Login() code in the mainwindow it validated correctly, then I placed the Login() in the LoginController class but it seems that the class can't retrieve the value of the textbox in mainwindow it always displays the "Invalid email address" even if I put the necessary value in the maindow textboxes

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you create a new `MainWindow` named `MainWindowPage` in the `Login` method, this has `Username_txtbox` with the default text of empty (I guess so). That `MainWindowPage` is not the main window of your program. You have to pass the current main window in the `Login` method. Modify your code as following (just a little modification):

```
public void Login(MainWindow MainWindowPage)
{
    DatabaseConnect.ConnectDatabase();
    //....
}
```

and...

```
private void Done_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoginControl.Login(this);
}
```

Comment: The code works! thanks, but the login() in keyenter method is having an error:

No overload for method 'Login' takes 0 arguments, every time I encounter this error I'm having hard time solving it

public void KeyEnter(KeyEventArgs e)

        
{
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                Login();
            }
        }

Comment: @RobertCadavos the modified `Login` method has 1 argument, you should find and replace all the references of `Login` methods in your project, there are many ways to pass object between classes, this is just a simple one, the point is your `Login` method has to use the `current MainWindowPage` not the one you create locally in `Login` method.